# Changing the label of a JQuery Mobile checkbox

Tags: checkbox, jquery-mobile

I have the following checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ui-5"/><label for="ui-5">checked</label>
```

I'd like to change its value to unchecked if its not checked and checked if it is checked. I've tried this code:

```
$("#ui-5").click(function(){
   $("label[for='ui-5']").text("unchecked");
});
```

It changes the label but the design of my checkbox becomes weird. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JQuery mobile changes the original html of the page, this seems to work:

```
 $("#ui-5").change(function () {
    $("label[for='ui-5'] span.ui-btn-text").text("unchecked");
 });
```

Comment: Searched all over the net for a solution, and this one actually worked. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @user1872256. Isn't there any `trigger("refresh")` solution?